# How can I cache data from API to Cache Storage in React PWA?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I built a Progressive Web App with ReactJS and have an issue. I am using mockApi to fetch the data.
When offline, my app doesn't work since the service worker only caches static assets.

How can I save HTTP GET calls from mockApi into the cache storage?

Answer (score 6):

Along with your static assets, you can define which URLs do you want to cache:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache_name';
var targetsToCache = [
  '/styles/myStyles.scss',
  'www.stackoverflow.com/'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll(targetsToCache);
      })
  );
});
```

Then you have to instruct your service worker to intercept the network requests and see if there is a match with the addresses in the `targetsToCache`:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {

         // This returns the previously cached response 
         // or fetch a new once if not already in the cache
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

I wrote a [series of articles about Progressive Web Apps](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da) if you are interested in learning more about it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try it.

Comment: Good. If my answer solved your question or lead you to the right direction, you should accept it.

Comment: Where should the provided code snippets go in create react app project?

Comment: @MarošBeťko you can create a file called "service-worker.js", for example, and write there all the logic related to the service worker: caching strategies, what to on install phase, etc.