# How to make the Service Worker cache data from API and update the cache when needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I transformed my React application into a PWA and it is working partially fine.

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@toricpope/transform-a-react-app-into-a-progressive-web-app-pwa-dea336bd96e6

However this article only shows how to cache static data and I also need to store data stemming from the server, I could do this following the instruction of the first answer of this post: [How can I cache data from API to Cache Storage in React PWA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708328/how-can-i-cache-data-from-api-to-cache-storage-in-react-pwa) and inserting the firebase adresses where the data is stored into the array `urlsToCache`, populated by the files that should be stored into the cache.

So far so good, however after the data be stored into the cache, the application stops fetching data from the server and loads the page only with data from the cache, even if the server is updated. This is what I need to fix.

In short, I need to fetch the data from the server, store it into the cache in order to use it when the application is offline and update the cache every time the server is reached.

I am trying to follow this guide, but without success: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#serving-suggestions

This is my worker.js file:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'pwa-task-manager';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/completed',
  '/index.html',
  '/static/js/main.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/0.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/1.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/bundle.js',
  '/calculadora',
  'https://calc-marmo.firebaseio.com/clientes.json',
  'https://calc-marmo.firebaseio.com/adm.json',
];

// Install a service worker
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

// Cache and return requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});

// Update a service worker
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  var cacheWhitelist = ['pwa-task-manager'];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

This sound like you need a *Network First* strategy which is not mention in the cookbook. This strategy is similar to *Network falling back to cache* but additionally stores the response always in the cache.

Explanation: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#network_first_network_falling_back_to_cache

Code sample (if you don't use workbox): https://gist.github.com/JMPerez/8ca8d5ffcc0cc45a8b4e1c279efd8a94

Comment: I kept digging and I could see that, I changed the perspective to `Network First` and it works great on localhost, however on a real host I am getting only the static data, the data from Firebase is not being cached, maybe the problem is how I configured it, I don't know. I also tried this example you posted, but I am getting the same problem. As an option I am storing static data into the cache and to dynamic data I am using `indexedDB`. If you have any idea why I am getting this problem I'd love to hear, since in this case I rather use cache than IDB, if not, thank you for your time anyway.

Comment: Firebase's Realtime Database uses websockets to communicate with the client. As far as I know WebSocket is not supported in the service worker. So you have to store the Firebase data in the IndexedDB as you mentioned. (That's how I did it)

Comment: may u share  a code snippet @how u did it